# Issue Retrieving JSON Files in react: CORS Settings in .htaccess Applied, but Second File Unreachable

Tags: reactjs, json, .htaccess, cors, fetch

I want to retrieve data from two JSON files using the following code. The file 'data.json' can be retrieved without any issues. However, the second file in the same directory is not retrievable. What could be the reason? CORS settings have also been added in the '.htaccess' file below.

The error that occurs during the retrieval of data from the 'history-price-gold18.json' file is:

Error:
`Access to fetch at 'https://takhminzan.com/fetch/history-price-gold18.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled`

index.jsx

```
 const [price, setPrice] = useState(gold18Price);
  const jsonFileURL = "https://takhminzan.com/fetch/data.json";
  const jsonFileHistoryPriceURL = "https://takhminzan.com/fetch/history-price-gold18.json";
  const [historyData, setHistoryData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = UITexts.Gold18;

    fetch(jsonFileURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("price", data.gold_18.close);
        setPrice(localStorage.getItem("price"));
      });

    fetch(jsonFileHistoryPriceURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("historyData", data.result.close);
        setHistoryData(localStorage.getItem("historyData"));
      });
  }, []);
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "https://app.takhminzan.com/*|http://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$" AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

I tested the following settings in the .htaccess file, but the issue persisted.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can't see a logical explanation for this so far. Where is the .htaccess located, inside the `fetch` folder, or one level above directly in the web root? (And if the latter, there isn't a different one inside `fetch`, that could somehow "undo" things again, no?) Both are static files; there is no URL rewriting involved to have one of the responses dynamically generated by a script? In that case, all that's left I can come up with, would be some proxy sitting before your own server perhaps, that still serves an old, cached result (that's still missing those CORS headers) ...?

Comment: .htaccess and fetch folder are both located in public_html folder.